# claim a lost watch

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

If someone claimed a lost watch, is it necessarily true that he took it? Or did he simply ask for it? The word "claim" seems to have multiple definitions.

> The police said John claimed the watch.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to formulate that question better.

Comment: Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *claim* has three basic connotations. The first is to make an assertion of the truth of a statement:

> **[1]** He **claimed** he saw a ghost

The second and third are declarations of ownership. Of these, the former states a demand of ownership based on right;

> **[2a]** He **claimed** the watch was his because his father had bequeathed it to him.

the latter asserts both ownership and actual possession:

> **[2b]** He landed on the island and **claimed** it for the King.

Without knowing more about the procedures for lost or stolen property, you can't tell whether your hypothetical visitor to the police was allowed to walk off with the watch (2b) or whether he had to be satisfied with merely filing a claim for it (2a).

Comment: Thank you. What dialect of English are you a native speaker of?

Comment: @Apollyon American English, but no regional dialect as I've lived in various parts of the US. I try to answer questions here from the point of view of standard, written English. This is more formal than the vernacular that most people use in conversation.

Comment: Aren't [1] and [2a] somewhat similar, way more than [2a] and [2b] are?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy You're right in that [1] and [2a] are statements of actuality. [2a] and [2b] are statements of ownership. But I don't know how to measure "way more."